# Unit tests for testing methods returning CompletableFuture always returns NullPointerException

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, completable-future, spring-boot-test

I have a SpringBoot Component and few methods. It returns CompletableFuture and I want to cover those lines with Unit Tests. But it always ends up in NullPointer Exception.

```
    @Component
    Class AsyncClass {

       // My implementation of RESTClient
       @Autowired
       RestClient httpClient;

       @Async
       public CompletableFuture<TestClass> getDetails() {
          // Retrieves the headers
          HttpHeaders headers = getHttpHeaders();
          HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

          InitiativeResponse initiativeResponse = httpClient.executeRequest(API_URL, HttpMethod.GET, request, Object.class).getBody();
          return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(TestClass);
       }

       private HttpHeaders getHttpHeaders(String userId) {
           HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
           headers.add(CONSUMER_ID, consumerId);
           headers.add(USER_ID, userId);
           return headers;
       }
    }
```

This works perfectly fine and I autowire this into my service class and get the results. The problem arises when I write unit test cases for this class.

```
     Class TestAsyncClass {
        @InjectMocks
        AsyncClass asyncClass;

        @BeforeEach
        void setUp() {
            openMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        void testGetDetails() {
            asyncClass.getDetails();
        }
     }
```

The above unit test fails with NullPointer Exception. Can you please help me on what am I missing?

The stacktrace simple shows

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.services.helper.TestAsyncClass.testGetDetails(TestAsyncClass.java:11)
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace you can show us?  Add it to your question.

Comment: I haven't used Mockito in a while, but I don't see any mocks defined here.  `@InjectMocks` isn't going to do much if you haven't defined any mocks.    My guess is that it is `httpClient.executeRequest()` that is causing the exception because you haven't told Mockito how to mock out the `httpClient` property.  This code doesn't seem complete in other respects as well (how is `getHttpHeaders` defined?), so I'm not sure what should be expected from this example.

Comment: @CryptoFool Included the getHeaders and stacktrace of the issue. Can you also direct me on how to mock the httpClient?

Comment: Well, given your error message, the problem is more basic than I thought.  Your attribute annotated with `@InjectMocks` is not being set at all, since accessing that value that is producing the NPE.  As I said, I haven't used Mockito in quite some time, so I can't help you with specifics.  Given where you're at, this is a problem of the most basic use of the framework.  I'd suggest that you find a working example that is similar to your situation and work back from there.  It sounds to me like you need to spend time better learning how to use Mockito in general.

Comment: If you need more help from the community, I'd suggest that you try to produce a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  This would this make it much easier for us to understand your problem and help you with it.  Not only that, it is often the case that the act of putting together a MRE leads to a solution to the problem.

Comment: Appreciate your replies. I got to know I lack the basic understanding of the Framework. I know what I am missing here now and working on to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure but do you have `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in your `TestAsyncClass` ? I have the gut feelings that the mocks are not initiated....